# Decomposing $\frac{m z^j}{1-z^m}$ for $0\le j\le m-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I have stumbled across the following conjecture. For $m\in\Bbb Z_{\ge2}$ let $\zeta_m=e^{2i\pi/m}$.
Thus we have $\zeta_m^m=1$ and $\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\zeta_m^l=0$.

> **Conjecture:** for all integers $j$ with $0\le j\le m-1$, we have $$p_{m,j}(z):=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\zeta_m^{-kj}}{1-\zeta_m^kz}=\frac{mz^j}{1-z^m}.\tag1$$

**Thoughts:** 
I have shown that $(1)$ holds for all $m$ when $j=0$, but no other general cases.

The conjecture is easy to show true for $m=2$, so that is left to the reader as a fun exercise. The case $m=3$ is a bit more messy, so I present it here. The messiness grows quadratically (the case-by-case proof for the $m=n$ involves $n^2-n$ terms at least) with $m$, and I have thus far not had the patience to check any $m\ge4$.

*Proof:* ($m=3$)

Since $1-z^m=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(1-\zeta_m^kz)$, we have that 
$$
(1-z^3)p_{3,1}(z)=(1-\zeta_3z)(1-\zeta_3^2z)+\zeta_3^2(1-z)(1-\zeta_3^2z)+\zeta_3(1-z)(1-\zeta_3z).
$$
This is 
$$\begin{align}
(1-z^3)p_{3,1}(z)=&1-(\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2)z+\zeta_3^3z^2\\
&+\zeta_3^2(1-(1+\zeta_3^2)z+\zeta_3^2z^2)\\
&+\zeta_3(1-(1+\zeta_3)z+\zeta_3z^2)\\
=&1+\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2\\
&-3(\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2)z\\
&+(1+\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2)z^2\\
=&3z.
\end{align}$$
Next up, we have
$$(1-z^3)p_{3,2}(z)=(1-\zeta_3z)(1-\zeta_3^2z)+\zeta_3(1-z)(1-\zeta_3z)+\zeta_3^2(1-z)(1-\zeta_3^2z).$$
This is
$$\begin{align}
(1-z^3)p_{3,2}(z)=&1-(\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2)z+z^2\\
&+\zeta_3(1-(1+\zeta_3^2)z+\zeta_3^2z^2)\\
&+\zeta_3^2(1-(1+\zeta_3)z+\zeta_3z^2)\\
=&1+\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2\\
&+(1+\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2)z\\
&+(1+1+1)z^2\\
=&3z^2.
\end{align}$$
And we are done. $\square$

**Progress on Proof:** Suppose that $A\subset \Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is a finite set of size $n$. Then we have 
$$\prod_{a\in A}(1-az)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-z)^k\sum_{{U\subset A}\atop{\#U=k}}\prod_{p\in U}p.$$
Taking $A=S_n=\{\zeta_n^k:k=0,1,...,n-1\}$ we have that $\prod_{a\in A}(1-az)=1-z^n$, so that
$$\sum_{{U\subset S_n}\atop{\#U=k}}\prod_{p\in U}p=0,\qquad \text{for }1\le k\le n-1.$$
Perhaps this will be useful when we note that 
$$(1-z^m)p_{m,j}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{v=0}^{m-1}(-z)^v\zeta_{m}^{-kj}\sum_{{U\subset S_m\setminus \{\zeta_m^k\}}\atop{\#U=v}}\prod_{p\in U}p.$$
Specifically, it could be used to show that $$(-1)^v\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\zeta_m^{-kj}\sum_{{U\subset S_m\setminus \{\zeta_m^k\}}\atop{\#U=v}}\prod_{p\in U}p=m\delta_{v,j},\tag2$$
with $\delta_{a,b}$ being the Kronecker delta. From this point I am stuck.

Can anyone help me prove $(2)$? or $(1)$? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ is simply an application of [PFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). Since $1-z^m=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(1-\zeta_m^k z)$, we have (for fixed $m$ and $j$) $$\frac{mz^j}{1-z^m}=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\alpha_k}{1-\zeta_m^k z},\quad\alpha_k=\lim_{z\to\zeta_m^{-k}}\frac{mz^j}{1-z^m}(1-\zeta_m^k z),$$ giving $(1)$ after evaluation of the limit.

Comment: oh. that easy, huh. Thanks! +1